# How to monitor Apache Kafka metrics?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, microservices, metrics

How can I build a microservice to monitor Kafka metrics?
I don't want to use the confluent control center or any other tool.

Comment: This question is a bit too general for stackoverflow. Please ask specific questions

Answer (score 3):

Before building anything like a microservice, I would explore the [kafka exporter](https://github.com/danielqsj/kafka_exporter) for Prometheus to expose Kafka metrics in prometheus format. You could then use Prometheus server to scrape these metrics and Grafana for dashboarding/visualisations. There's other tools you could use for scraping instead of Prometheus/Grafana, e.g. Elastic Metricbeat (which I mention because you've tagged the question with 'elasticsearch'), but the Prometheus/Grafana combination is quite easy to get up and running - there's also out-of-the-box Grafana dashboards that you can install without having to set this up manually e.g. [this one](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/721).

Comment: I want to use Elasticsearch and Kibana